# Laravel 8 Get Products as per category id data

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have a category table with category id, name and parent_id and I have a product table having a column category_id that stores multiple category id like ["1", "2", "4"].

Now I'm having a problem in getting product details from the product table which has an id column.

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $this->catslug)->get()->first();
        $data = array();
        foreach($category as $cat){
            $data['category'] = $cat->id;
            $data['products'] = DB::table('products')
                                ->whereJsonContains('category_id', json_decode($cat->id))
                                ->inRandomOrder()->limit(8)->get();
        }
dd($data);
```

Comment: You probably don’t need to use `json_decode`. Why are you storing your database like this? A simple relationship would a lot easier https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many